# Factoring and algebra

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm reading Calculus for dummies but got stuck on the following

[image: Issue]

The line "Factor x out of the denominator." is the part I do not understand.
How is it possible to go from sqrt(x^2 + x) + x 
to
x(sqrt(1 + 1/x) + 1) ?

Comment: How many more identical answers are we gonna get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ \sqrt{x^2+x}+x=\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{1}{x})}+x$$
$$\text{now remember that }\sqrt{x^2}=|x|, \text{ and for}\ x\to+\infty, |x|=x$$
$$\text{so it becomes}$$
$$\sqrt{x^2}.\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+x=x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+x=x(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

Noting that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=x$ for $x\gt 0$, we have
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+x}+x&=\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac 1x\right)}+x\\&=\sqrt{x^2}\cdot \sqrt{1+\frac 1x}+x\\&=x\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}+x\\&=x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 1x}+1\right).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

For any non-negative real numbers $a,b$ we have $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$.

Here, we have $\sqrt{x^2+x} = \sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)} = \sqrt{x^2} \cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} = x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}$ (Since $x$ is positive).

Thus, $\sqrt{x^2+x}+x = x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+x = x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1\right)$.